# PrimeFaces data table In-Cell Editing : I can't get the edited object

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, celleditorlistener

I'm experimenting with [DataTable - Cell Editing](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableCellEditing.jsf) as shown in PrimeFaces showcase. I've modified the Facelets code as consequence of this question: [primefaces in-cell-editing not update data in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19973172/primefaces-in-cell-editing-not-update-data-in-database) because the `<p:ajax event="cellEdit">` didn't update the entire data table.

```
<h:form id="form">            
    <p:outputPanel id="testContainer" deferred="true">   
        <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />  
        <p:remoteCommand name="onCellEdit" action="#{articlesbean.onCellEdit()}" update=":form:messages" />
        <p:dataTable id="cars" var="car" value="#{articlesbean.LMatpilotaccess1}" editable="true" editMode="cell" widgetVar="carsTable" update=":cars">  
            <p:ajax event="cellEdit" oncomplete="onCellEdit()"  /> 
            ...
        </p:dataTable>  
    </p:outputPanel> 
</h:form>
```

The remote command action method is definied as follows:

```
public void onCellEdit(CellEditEvent event) {  
    Object oldValue = event.getOldValue();  
    Object newValue = event.getNewValue();  

    if(newValue != null && !newValue.equals(oldValue)) {  
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Cell Changed", "Old: " + oldValue + ", New:" + newValue);  
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);  
    }  
}
```

However, this method is never invoked and the following exception is thrown:

```
javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: Method not found: com.pfe.controller.ArticlesBean@1bb3a11.onCellEdit()
```

When I remove the `CellEditEvent` argument, then it works. But I actually need the old and the new value. How can I proceed?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{orderDetailController.onCellEditTableComplete}" update=":formGeneral:tabViewGeneral:growl :formGeneral:tabViewGeneral:OrderHeaderTableComplete"/>

   <p:cellEditor>  
       <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{orderDetail.quantity}" /></f:facet>  
       <f:facet name="input">
            <p:inputText id="modelInput" value="#{orderDetail.quantity}" valueChangeListener="#{orderDetailController.onValueQuantityChange}"/></f:facet>  
   </p:cellEditor>
```

And

```
public void onValueQuantityChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    newQuantity = (Integer) event.getNewValue();
}
```

You won't be able to perform the `!newValue.equals(oldValue)` test comparison but you will be able to obtain your answer.

```
public void onCellEditTableComplete(CellEditEvent event) {
    DataTable dataTable = (DataTable) event.getSource();
    OrderDetail oDetail = (OrderDetail) dataTable.getRowData();
    oDetail.setQuantity(newQuantity);
    ...
}
```

Forget the `p:remoteCommand` as outside the `p:dataTable` you have not the 'desired' `CellEditEvent`.

- EDITED -

If for the same table, you have to show some calculations based in this cell, you should call it from a p:remoteCommand. Just add `oncomplete="onCellEditTableComplete()"` and do the update from outside the table

```
<p:remoteCommand name="onCellEditTableComplete" update=":formGeneral:tabViewGeneral:OrderHeaderTableComplete " />
   <p:dataTable ...>


        <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{orderDetailController.onCellEditTableComplete}" 
                                update=":formGeneral:tabViewGeneral:growl :formGeneral:tabViewGeneral:OrderHeaderTableResume" 
                                oncomplete="onCellEditTableComplete()"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
<h:form id="form">            
    <p:outputPanel id="testContainer" deferred="true">  
        <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />  
        <p:remoteCommand name="onCellEdit" action="#{articlesbean.onCellEdit()}" update=":form:messages" />
        <p:dataTable id="cars" var="car" value="#{articlesbean.LMatpilotaccess1}" editable="true" editMode="cell" widgetVar="carsTable" update=":cars">  
            <p:ajax event="cellEdit" oncomplete="onCellEdit()"  /> 
            ...
        </p:dataTable>  
  </h:form>
</p:outputPanel>
```

[]'s