# Primefaces datatable, update row oncelledit

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, tablecelleditor

I have primefaces datatable and i want to update specific column or entire row on cell edit. Value in edited cell determines value in other column in the same row.

I tried to update component from onCellEdit method but no success:

```
String targetTypeColumn = ((DataTable)event.getSource()).getClientId(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()) +
                  ":" + event.getRowIndex() + ":editor";

RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(targetTypeColumn);
```

Column have cell editor:

```
<p:column id="tgtType" styleClass="mapDetsTblColTypeTgt" headerText="Target Type">
    <p:cellEditor id="editor" rendered="...">
        <f:facet name="output">
            <h:outputText  value="..." />
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="input">
            <p:inputText value="..." styleClass="mapDetsTblInput" onselect="this.value=this.value" />
        </f:facet>
    </p:cellEditor>
    <h:outputText value="..." rendered="!..."/>
</p:column>
```

Any ideas?

I don't want to update whole datatable because this is waste of time.

Edit:

I tried to update datatable during on cell edit

```
<p:dataTable id="mapperDetailsTable" styleClass="mapperDetailsTable" widgetVar="mapperDetailsTable"
                ..... >

                <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{bean.onCellEdit}" update=":mapperDetailsForm:growlMapper mapperDetailsTable"
                oncomplete="handleCellEdit(args);" />
......
```

but no effect. Next cell not updated. Is it correct what i wrote? I'm using autoComplete in edited cell so i don't have update attribute.

```
<p:cellEditor rendered="#{guiUtils.isEditable(mapperCtrl, fieldMapping)}">
    <f:facet name="output">
        <h:outputText value="#{fieldMapping.fieldNameTgt}"/>
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="input">
        <p:autoComplete value="#{fieldMapping.fieldNameTgt}" completeMethod="#{mapperCtrl.dmUtils.completeTargetFields}" >
            <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{mapperCtrl.action}" process="mapperDetailsTable"/> 
            <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{mapperCtrl.action}" process="mapperDetailsTable"/> 
        </p:autoComplete>
    </f:facet>
</p:cellEditor>
```

Edit2:

I checked and value is updated on the correct element in the list.

When i used solution from this thread(reload datatable): [Updating entire <p:dataTable> on complete of <p:ajax event="cellEdit">](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548838/updating-entire-pdatatable-on-complete-of-pajax-event-celledit)
everything is ok. So value is updated correctly but how to refresh row or cell only?

Edid 3:

I found out that i can update cell using commandButton

```
<p:column>
.....
                    <p:commandButton value="updateTgtRow" id="updateTgtRow"  process="@this" ajax="true" immediate="true" update="outputType inputType"/>
</p:column>
```

After click in button cell is updated without reload table. But how to call click on that button after cell edit? When i added oncomplete, cell edit don't work. Cells are read only. Any idea?

```
<p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{mapperCtrl.onCellEdit}" 
                    process="@this" oncomplete="#(updateTgtRow).click()"/>
```

Comment: The default behavior of `update="tableId"` specifically during `cellEdit` event is already that it updates only the current row. Have you actually tried/investigated it? Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548838 (which actually asks for the other way round)

Comment: @BalusC: Are you sure the default for `cellEdit` is to update the current **row**? (did not try, don't use row and cell edit)

Comment: Value is updated on correct element in the list.

Comment: Updating entire table makes some problems to me. When i edit cells fast i lost focus on next edited cell (refresh is called) and wired thins happen with autocomplete elements. After refresh datatable cellEdit is called on autoComplete click. It calls refresh datatable and focus lost :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve my problem using p:commandButton component

In cell i added

```
<p:commandButton style="display: none" value="updateTgtRow" id="updateTgtRow"  process="@this" ajax="true" immediate="true" update="outputTgtType inputTgtType"/>
```

It updates fields from other cells (outputTgtType and inputTgtType). In bean i call click on that button

```
String componentId = ((DataTable) event.getSource()).getClientId(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()) + ":"
                        + event.getRowIndex() + ":updateTgtRow";

RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("document.getElementById('" + componentId + "').click()");
```

It looks like hack but it works. This solution update specific cells in currently edited row.

Comment: I think this should be posted as a feature request for future release of Primefaces